# embedded youtube video is not getting unmute while autoplaying the video

Tags: html

I have this iframe tag

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uNRGWVJ10gQ?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow='autoplay' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to auto play the video with sound on. But i am not able to do that. The video is auto playing but in mute.
Is there any solution to do that?

Comment: try add `&mute=0` to link. Like that - `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uNRGWVJ10gQ?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&mute=0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing amp; from the iframe source like this:-

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uNRGWVJ10gQ?rel=0&autoplay=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow='autoplay' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It should be autoplaying the video with audio on.

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked. Is there any work around that I can do the same in web view as it not allowing to auto play itself.